# Blender thinks there's a seam when UV unwrapping after applying mirror modifier

Tags: uv

hoping you can help with this. Bit of a weird one.

Applied the mirror modifier and then started UV unwrapping, quickly noticed that the UV splits down the middle where the mirror point was. It's almost like Blender thinks there's a seam here. The issue goes away when using Smart UV, but using the general Unwrap method shows the issue. I've made sure there's no overlapping verts. Scale and location are all applied.

Do I need to do UV unwrapping BEFORE applying the mirror modifier? Does Blender ALWAYS see the mirror point as a seam?[image: Seam down the middle]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is there an internal face where the mirror joined? If so, delete it and try again.

Comment: could you please share your object or at least show the UV Editor? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I'm with @JohnEason here, this looks like there might be internal faces. Or at least I get a similar result when I have internal faces on a test object.

Comment: You guys are heroes, turns out there were internal faces I forgot to sort out before applying the mirror modifier. Deleted them and unwrapped again and it looks good! Thanks a lot guys! This was driving me a bit crazy!